# JavaScript Array result disappear

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm writing a function that pass in a string called "term" to search in my MongoDB, then add its results to an existed empty array of results called "result[]":

```
var searchAndAddToResults = (result, term)=> {
  Place.find({ $or: [
    {name: term}, {category: term}
  ] }, places=> {
    for (let i in places) {
      if (!itemExists(result, places[i].toObject())) {
        result.push(places[i].toObject())
      }
    }
    console.log(result)   // result isn't empty, which is good
  })
  console.log(result)   // result is empty, which is bad and weird
  return result    // this returned result is also empty, THIS is the real problem
}
```

Can anyone help me with restructuring this code to get it work? Thanks

Comment: The find operation is asynchronous, so when you make the request, the console.log outside the callback is called immediately, before the find returns any results.

Comment: I can tell that, but the problem is how to make sure my returned result value is correct instead of being empty?

Comment: That's because you're returning synchronously - return a promise instead.

Answer (score 0):

These calls are asynchronous - which is why you are getting results in succcess callback of `Place.find()` and finding one outside of the method. Because as soon as `Place.find()` is called the next line is executed. So it'll be great if you learn to work with these asynchronous calls of javascript.

Comment: but the problem is my returned result is also empty

Comment: I think this is a great place where you'll get different scenarios and answers on how to processing results in an asynchronous call - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron